# Bedienen oder arbeiten?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, standard-german

Can I use both or there is some rule behind using this verbs separately?

> Ich arbeite mit dem Computer
>
> Ich bediene mich des Computers

Welche ist richtig?

Comment: They are both valid German sentences (the latter sounding slightly outdated), but they have different meanings. What do you want to say?

Comment: @Raketenolli No, they have the same meaning. The second one is just very old fashioned.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   Objection! *Ich bediene mich des Computers* (although totally old-fashioned indeed) can mean any possible use of a computer, e.g. for gaming. It is simply a form of saying ***I use a computer***. Opposed to that, *Ich arbeite mit dem Computer* would be used for activities that are seen as deserving to be classified as "work". You could say *Ich bediene mich des Computers zum Spielen* (you would sound silly, but okay, why not), but you cannot say *Ich arbeite mit dem Computer zum Spielen* or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich arbeite mit dem Computer.

*I work with the computer.*

> Ich bediene den Computer.

*I operate the computer.*

Those two are common.

> Ich bediene mich des Computers.

*I avail myself of the computer.*

This one is rather old-fashioned. You will find it nevertheless when police describes the instruments of a crime.

> Die Täter brachen in den Markt ein und bedienten sich dazu eines zuvor auf einer nahen Baustelle entwendeten Radladers.

If you like to hear such stilted speech, watch the *Aktenzeichen XY* show of the German *ZDF* TV channel. Old or new episodes, it doesn't matter. The speaker uses that *amtliche Sprache* by purpose, it seems.

Comment: I particularly like the purposefully odd temporal consecutiveness in the police report example. That's how they indeed often write. A more language-aware person would say: *Die Täter brachen in den Markt ein. Sie bedienten sich dazu eines zuvor auf einer nahen Baustelle entwendeten Radladers.* That's because the *und* in the original sentence suggests a chronological order which is contrafactual: the perpetrators doubtlessly first took the loader, then broke into the shop.